# Where is Contact Type stored? (google/ phone)

Tags: contacts

I am trying to find where Contact type ( Google/Phone) is stored and how to access it.  I thought I could access the class in the android.provider.contacts.contact.commonDatakinds package. However i could not find any information on the data field. Any help on contactscontact data field documentation and Contact Type would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can query to RawContacts's content_uri with Rawcontacts.ACCOUNT_NAME and RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE to get it.